# multiple relationships in shipping graph noe4j using python

Tags: python, neo4j, graph-databases, relation

I need help with creating many:many relations. My database is about shipping products from supplier to buyer. Now I am stuck with creating relations which would describe path of supplied product.
My code:

```
pip install neo4j
pip install py2neo
pip install graphdatascience
from graphdatascience import GraphDataScience
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
import logging
import sys
driver = GraphDatabase.driver("neo4j://localhost:7687",
                              auth=("neo4j", "test"))

def create_country(tx, name,continent,population_mln):
    tx.run("CREATE (a:Country {name: $name,continent: $continent,population_mln: $population_mln})", name=name,continent=continent,population_mln=population_mln)

def create_shop(tx, name,founded,revenue_mlrd):
    tx.run("CREATE (b:Shop {name: $name,founded: $founded,revenue_mlrd: $revenue_mlrd})", name=name,founded=founded,revenue_mlrd=revenue_mlrd)

def create_buyer(tx, name,birth_date,purchases):
    tx.run("CREATE (c:Buyer {name: $name,birth_date: $birth_date,purchases: $purchases})", name=name,birth_date=birth_date,purchases=purchases)

def operates_from(tx, name, shop_name):
    tx.run("MERGE (b:Shop {name: $shop_name}) "
           "MERGE (a:Country {name: $name}) "
           "MERGE (b)-[:OPERATES_from]->(a)",
           name=name, shop_name=shop_name)
def buys_from(tx, name, buyer_name):
    tx.run("MERGE (b:Shop {name: $name}) "
           "MERGE (c:Buyer {name: $buyer_name}) "
           "MERGE (c)-[:buys_from]->(b)",
           name=name, buyer_name=buyer_name)
def lives_in(tx, name, buyer_name):
    tx.run("MERGE (a:Country {name: $name}) "
           "MERGE (c:Buyer {name: $buyer_name}) "
           "MERGE (c)-[:lives_in]->(a)",
           name=name, buyer_name=buyer_name)
with driver.session() as session:
    session.execute_write(create_country, "China","Asia",1412)
    session.execute_write(create_country, "US","North America",331.9)
    session.execute_write(create_country, "UK","Europe",67)
    session.execute_write(create_country, "Poland","Europe",37)
    session.execute_write(create_country, "Lithuania","Europe",2.7)
    session.execute_write(create_country, "Turkey",["Europe","Asia"],85)
    session.execute_write(create_country, "Latvia","Europe",1.8)
    session.execute_write(create_country, "Slovakia","Europe",5.4)
    session.execute_write(create_country, "Spain","Europe",47.3)
    session.execute_write(create_country, "Germany","Europe",83.1)
    session.execute_write(create_shop, "Amazon",1994,469.8)
    session.execute_write(create_shop, "Ebay",1995,10.27)
    session.execute_write(create_shop, "Wish",2011,2.1)
    session.execute_write(create_shop, "AliExpress",2010,134000.5)
    session.execute_write(create_shop, "JD.com",1998,951.6)
    session.execute_write(create_buyer, "Tomas Tomaitis",1998,20)
    session.execute_write(create_buyer, "John Iglesias",1973,2)
    session.execute_write(create_buyer, "Ann Milosh",1989,113)
    session.execute_write(create_buyer, "Saule Saulyte",2000,13)
    session.execute_write(create_buyer, "Sam Booth",1968,1)
    session.execute_write(operates_from, "US", "Amazon")
    session.execute_write(operates_from, "US", "Ebay")
    session.execute_write(operates_from, "US", "Wish")
    session.execute_write(operates_from, "China", "AliExpress")
    session.execute_write(operates_from, "China", "JD.com")
    session.execute_write(create_buyer, "Janis Timma",1989,5)
    session.execute_write(buys_from, "Amazon", "Tomas Tomaitis")
    session.execute_write(buys_from, "Amazon", "Ann Milosh")
    session.execute_write(buys_from, "Wish", "Saule Saulyte")
    session.execute_write(buys_from, "JD.com", "John Iglesias")
    session.execute_write(buys_from, "Ebay", "Sam Booth")
    session.execute_write(buys_from, "AliExpress", "Janis Timma")
    session.execute_write(lives_in, "Latvia","Janis Timma")
    session.execute_write(lives_in, "Lithuania","Saule Saulyte")
    session.execute_write(lives_in, "Spain","John Iglesias")
    session.execute_write(lives_in, "US","Sam Booth")
    session.execute_write(lives_in, "Slovakia","Ann Milosh")
    session.execute_write(lives_in, "Lithuania","Tomas Tomaitis")
    session.execute_write(shipping_through, "US","Janis Timma")
    session.execute_write(lives_in, "Lithuania","Saule Saulyte")
    session.execute_write(lives_in, "Spain","John Iglesias")
    session.execute_write(lives_in, "US","Sam Booth")
    session.execute_write(lives_in, "Slovakia","Ann Milosh")
    session.execute_write(lives_in, "Lithuania","Tomas Tomaitis")

driver.close()
```

What I need to do is to create relationships through which countries product was shipped. For example from Amazon parcell is shipped to Spain and them shipped to final location Slovakia.

```
(:Shop)-[:SHIPPING ]->(:Country1)-[:SHIPPING TO]->(:Country2)
```

Comment: what is your input for creating the :SHIPPING relationships?

Comment: I tried something like this, but it creates shop as country and duplicates it. Tried to use MATCH instead of MERGE what nothing happens:
```def shipping_through(tx, shop_name,name,scountry):

    tx.run(" MERGE (b:Shop {name: $shop_name}"
           " MERGE (a:Country {name: $name})"
           " MERGE (s:Country{name: $scountry}"
           "\nMERGE (b)-[:shipping_to]->(s)-[:shipping_to]->(a) RETURN b.name",
           name=name,shop_name=shop_name,scountry=scountry)```

Comment: ensure that the values that you passed (name, shop_name,scountry) are correct. what are the values you passed?